# Como mudo o background para uma imagem no kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, python-kivy, kivy

tipo já tentei isso uma vez e percebi que não da pra mudar tamanho de Textura,
sem mais elongas vamos para os códigos
Código Python:

```
'''
3DPNG
Directed by JonDev2023
Created by JonDev2023
Released by JonDev2023
Programmed by JonDev2023
'''

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class ADM(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Modeling(Screen):
    pass

class Runner(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = '3DPNG'
        return Builder.load_file('index.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Runner().run()
```

Código Kivy:

```
ADM:
    Modeling:
        name: 'modeling'

<Modeling>:
    FloatLayout:
        Canvas:
```

Answer (score 0):

Para usar uma imagem como background podemos definir o campo "source" e com os campos "size" e "pos" especificamos o tamanho.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

Builder.load_file('index.kv')

class ADM(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Modeling(Screen):
    pass

class Runner(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = '3DPNG'
        self.adm = ADM()
        return self.adm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Runner().run()
```

```
<ADM>:
    Modeling:
        name: 'modeling'

<Modeling>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'bg.jpg'
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```